# Marketing Cloud - unable to uninstall a package

Tags: marketing-cloud, appexchange

I installed in my business unit a package called **Deployment Manager** from appexchange and I am looking for a way to uninstall it.

If I go to `Setup > Apps > Installed Packages` I see the list of installed packages but there is no icon to uninstall it.

What should I do to uninstall it?
Here is the installed packages page
[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to be an admin in all MIDs to delete a package as outlined in this help page '[Create and Install Packages](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-app-development.meta/mc-app-development/install-packages.htm)'

> You can uninstall packages and apps installed from AppExchange or an implementation partner. Only users with the Installed Packages | Administer permission and access to all the accounts in the enterprise can uninstall a package or app. The package or app is uninstalled from all accounts in the enterprise.

Comment: thanks, because I personally installed the package, I supposed to have the permissions to uninstall it.

Answer (score 2):

You need to click on the package and then you will be able to delete it using the Delete button on the top right of the screen:

[image]

Comment: thanks Rachid, from where shall I click on the package?

Comment: Click on the package's name when you are at: Setup > Apps > Installed Packages

Comment: no, it does not appear the same layout as u did, I will share the view